# adding userControl to tabControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, tabcontrol

how can i insert a userControl that contains buttons,lables to TabControl page in c#? (what is the code)

Notes:

- the tabControl is inside a userControl because i need this tabControl for other forms.
- i am using visual Studio 2008.

Code:

```
public Courses()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ucAction1.tpDelete // (userControl name,firts tabControl tabPage), i dont know how to move on from here?
}
```

Comment: So which is it-- is the usercontrol inside the tabcontrol, or the tabcontrol inside the usercontrol?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to add the usercontrol manually to the tabpage:

```
tabPage1.Controls.Add(ucAction1);
```

**Update:**

I "think" I understand your issue.  In your tabcontrol inside your usercontrol, change the Modifiers property of each TabPage to Public.  Then you can access it:

```
ucAction1.tabPage1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
```

Comment: the userControl inside the tabControl and also tabControl is in userControl. to make it simplier i need to insert something (not matter what) to tabControl that is inside userControl

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub addTabPage(ByVal Title As String)
    Dim TPage As New TabPage(Title)
    Dim UCInstance As New UControl()
    TPage.Controls.Add(UCInstance)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TPage)
    UCInstance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

call `UserControl1` on `tapPage1` like this

```cs
UserControl1 myUserControl = new UserControl1();

myUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

tabPage1.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
```